# Created Date of file via ftp

Tags: python, web2py, filezilla, ftplib

Good Day!

How to get created date of a file via ftp?.
Im using web2py,python,ftplib and filezilla as a ftp server. I can get the modified date via f.sendcmd('MDTM '+filename).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You have something like the following:

```
connection = ftplib.FTP(**ftpCredentials)
modifiedTime = connection.sendcmd('MDTM ' + fileName)
# successful response: '213 20120222090254'
```

To interpret the modified time, you should do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.strptime(modifiedTime[4:], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").strftime("%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
# prints something like 01 January 1970 09:30:01
```

Source: [this blog post @ http://alexharvey.eu/code/python/get-a-files-last-modified-datetime-using-python/](http://alexharvey.eu/code/python/get-a-files-last-modified-datetime-using-python/)

Comment: FTP servers don't support querying of file creation date. Your best hope for finding information on a particular file is the command `MLST` which may return something like: `size*;type*;perm*;create*;modify*; `

Comment: I know this is an old post, but... standards must have evolved because this method now works fine for me on Python 3+, for those who may stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to change the file modification time, I use an FTP client on the console.
Log on to a remote FTP ftp *ftp.dic.com*

- *cd* commands go to the correct directory
- ***SITE*** command to move the extended command mode
- *UTIME **somefile.txt** 20050101123000 20050101123000 20050101123000 UTC*

change the access time, modification time, it's time to create a directory on 2005-01-01 12:30:00 **somefile.txt**

Complete example:

> site UTIME somefile.txt 20150331122000 20150331122000 20150331122000 UTC

Of course you can use this command in any ftp client.